Why does fgetcsv not return the array?
There is something happening in a while loop for fgetcsv.  I have never seen before.
Has anyone else seen it?  I have written code before to extract data from a csv file and have never had this problem.
When I do the extract with individual call the data is extracted just fine.  I have included my examples.
This is my little test fill:
First Name,Last Name
Ann,Bessire
Kimberly,Biggerstaff
Mary,Brice
When I do this:
$col_data = fgetcsv($csvfile);
print_r($col_data);
$col_data = fgetcsv($csvfile);
print_r($col_data);
$col_data = fgetcsv($csvfile);
print_r($col_data);
$col_data = fgetcsv($csvfile);
print_r($col_data);

The output looks like this;
Array ( [0] => First Name [1] => Last Name )
Array ( [0] => Ann [1] => Bessire )
Array ( [0] => Kimberly [1] => Biggerstaff )
Array ( [0] => Mary [1] => Brice )

If I do this:
while ($col_data = fgetcsv($csvfile) !== false){
    print_r($col_data);
}

The output looks like this:
1111111111111111111111111111111111

I am baffled on what is going on.

You're assigning fgetcsv($csvfile) !== false to $col_data.

Note the extra parentheses in the example in the manual.

Go read https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php to un-baffle yourself.

print_r() is not a good debugging tool. If, as here, you have booleans, you'll get 1 for true and empty string for false. Compare with e.g. var_dump(): https://3v4l.org/7BuY1#v8.3.8

fixing your while loop:
while (($col_data = fgetcsv($csvfile)) !== false){
    print_r($col_data);
}

